# Where can I find the rules for the combo-box-table-cell css style?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

In the JavaFX class `ComboBoxTableCell`, there is a line of code that says

```
this.getStyleClass().add("combo-box-table-cell");
```

I want to see how the selectors and rules are defined for the combo-box-table-cell CSS class, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Does anyone know where I can look to find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find that style class in `caspian.css` nor in `modena.css`.

Actually, a cell with a `ComboBoxTableCell` as a cell factory may have other style classes like `cell`, `indexed-cell`, `table-cell` or `table-column`, and only `table-cell` has some rules defined on `modena.css`.

It's added so you can hook up easily your styling if you need to, overriding default rules from `table-cell` only in this type of cell, for instance:

```
.combo-box-table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: lightgrey;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that make sense now! Do you know where to find the CSS that styles the combo box when it appears in a table cell (like for a ComboBoxTableCell it doesn't have the button outline, etc.)? Where is that styling coming from?

Comment: When the cell is not in edit mode, it shows a `Label`. If you click on it it changes to a regular `ComboBox`.  To style the cell, find in modena.css the rules defined at the style class `table-cell`. As I said in my answer, you can use `combo-box-table-cell` to style the cell when it's not edited and `combo-box` to style the combo.